# Using Variables for Inserting Values into a SQL DB Table in Java

Tags: java, sql, t-sql

I'm working on a Lab from the Gaddis Java textbook, and I'm attempting to insert an entry into a T-SQL database table of sports teams using a variable to represent the team name.

**Code**

```
do
{
    // ADD LINES FOR TASK #3 HERE
    // Prompt the user for a new team name
    System.out.println("Enter new team name: ");
    teamName = keyboard.nextLine();

    // Update the Teams table
    String sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO Teams" +
                          "VALUES " + teamName + ", 0, 0, 0";
    int rows = stmt.executeUpdate(sqlStatement);

    System.out.print("Do you want to enter " +
                             "another team: ");
    ans = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);

} while(ans == 'Y'|| ans == 'y');
```

When entering the value `Braves` I get the error `Incorrect syntax near 'Braves'.`

Thanks in advance for any and all assistance!

**UPDATE 01**

Thanks to feedback I've updated my SQL statement, as well as specifying the column names to ensure the order is correct.

```
// Update the Teams table
String sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO Teams" +
                      "(TeamName, Wins, Losses, Ties)" +
                      "VALUES (" + teamName + " , 0, 0, 0)";       
int rows = stmt.executeUpdate(sqlStatement);
```

However, now I get the error `ERROR: Invalid column name 'Braves'.` when entering in `Braves` when prompted. I don't understand why as I am specifying the variable `teamName` as the value.

**SOLVED**

Thanks to @MrLY I've solved the issue! Thanks to everyone else that helped as well!

Comment: `INSERT INTO TeamsVALUES Braves, 0, 0, 0` does not seem like valid SQL syntax to me...

Comment: @fabian The first value is a string of the TeamName and my variable 'teamName' represents a team name collected from user input. The 0's represent the initial scores of Wins, Losses, and Ties. How would you suggest I fix this statement?

Comment: i think the code you post is not the reason of your problem, did you debug your code @ryderd ? or at least can you put more code that you suspect is the problem?

Comment: @ryderd i edit my answer you can check it now, i think the problem now is the `'  '` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your query

```
String sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO Teams" +"VALUES " + teamName + ", 0, 0, 0";
int rows = stmt.executeUpdate(sqlStatement);
```

Your insert query should be like this:

```
INSERT INTO Teams VALUES(att1, att2, att3, ...);
```

so change your query to be like this:

```
 String sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO Teams " +"VALUES( " + teamName + ", 0, 0, 0)";
```

if you want to insert a specific attribute then you should to create your query like this:

```
String sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO Teams(att1, att2, att2, att2) " +"VALUES( " + teamName + ", 0, 0, 0)";
```

**Edit**

your String should be between two `'my string'`, so your query should be like this now:

```
String sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO Teams" +
                      "(TeamName, Wins, Losses, Ties)" +
                      "VALUES ('" + teamName + "' , 0, 0, 0)";
```

**N.B**

I advice to use prepared statement it more useful and more safe than this way

you can learn more about [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: I've updated my OP with more code that I've developed with help from your post.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write with a good sql syntax. Try something like this :

```
 String sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO Teams " +
                      "VALUES (" + teamName + ", 0, 0, 0)";
```